# Stored procedure parameters not working in concat

Tags: mysql

Below is the procedure i am using.I am unable to use parameters(ptodate timestamp,pfromdate timestamp)of procedure in concatenate statement provided below.Please suggest how to use parameters of procedure in below procedure to get data from start and end date provided in parameters.When i run this procedure error generates that "query terminated".Error occurs at line where I used (ptodate timestamp,pfromdate timestamp) parameters in concat statement. please suggest.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root `@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE`procedurename`(phonecode int,ptodate timestamp,pfromdate timestamp)
BEGIN
if(phonecode=880)
then
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
 CONCAT(
 'SUM(IF(a.category_name = ''',
 a.category_name,
 ''',1,0)) AS ',
 "'",p.name,"'"
 )
 )into @SQL
 FROM tablea a 
JOIN tableb p ON a.category_name=p.id
where a.sender_country_code=880
and a.created_datetime>ptodate and a.created_datetime<pfromdate;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE(a.date_time),
', @sql, ' 
FROM edr_im a 
JOIN package p ON a.category_name=p.id
WHERE a.message_type="sticker"
and 
a.sender_country_code=880 and a.created_datetime>',ptodate,' and    a.created_datetime<',pfromdate,'
GROUP BY 1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
end if;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the dates.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE(a.date_time),
', @sql, ' 
FROM edr_im a 
JOIN package p ON a.category_name=p.id
WHERE a.message_type="sticker"
and 
a.sender_country_code=880 and a.created_datetime>"',ptodate,'" and    a.created_datetime<"',pfromdate,'"
GROUP BY 1');
```

Comment: It works.Thanks a lot Barmar .I really Appreciate your quick response. :)